# Responsive header with a weird webkit bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, responsive-design

I'm currently building a new website but there is a small hiccup on webkit browsers.

http://typework.github.io/green-life/

If you browse to the url above and resize the browser to mobile size.
Open the navigation (click only once on the hamburger) and resize back to full screen. You can see that my navigation moved to the left. When you keep resizing the browser you see that it moves more and more to the left.

In Firefox I do not have this problem, Safari and Chrome does.

I used plain and simple JavaScript:

```
$('.menu-link').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav').toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

And simple display: block css:

```
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 31px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}
@media(max-width: 992px) {
    .nav {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: none;
        clear: both;
        width: 100 %;
    }
    .nav.active {
        display: block;
    }
```

I do not seem to find the bug however. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem in the `nav li`, change it `display:inline-block.`

```
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

I think this will solve your issue.

also make it `display block` in media query

Comment: That did the job, I can't believe that I missed something so simple. thank you very much!